# How to track the Terminal / createTerminal state , that is it busy running a script

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my application i am required to handle User commands. So each command or interaction user has will start a terminal using createTerminal vscode API , will run the command (i can always also use script to run these commands).

However i need to notify user when the createTerminal is done executing command. For example user says run a make file file  or build a application the createterminal starts building the make file however i have below code to track check state of each terminal and it does not know when the commands are done executing and terminal is idle.
const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal(`Processing command ${SomeUserCommand}`);
terminal.sendText(SomeUserCommand);
terminal.show(true);

then later i have loop to track the status of these  terminals

```
    const currentTerminals = vscode.window.terminals;
    console.log("\n Current terminals .");

    for (let i = 0; i < currentTerminals.length; i++) {
        const oneterminal = currentTerminals[i];

        console.log("\n terminal process id = ", oneterminal.processId);
        console.log(",  name = ", oneterminal.name)
        console.log(" state = ", oneterminal.state)
        console.log(",  exitStatus = ", oneterminal.exitStatus)
    }
     state =  {isInteractedWith: true}
```

example below o/p I cannot tell if terminal is completed running my commands so i can prompt the user the task is completed.
o/p of above chek
state =  {isInteractedWith: true}
exitStatus =  undefined

Comment: i want to implement something like 
- start executing command
- When command execution is completed, notify user , or I can also start running next command in queue  using terminal.sendText)

Comment: are you writing a VS Code extension? if so, you should add the [tag:vscode-extensions] tag to your question's tags.